# Can't get bean from external project

Tags: java, spring

I have two projects: user-services and datamodel-dao.
In user-services I'm trying to get UserDao from datamodel-dao, but I get this errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/khliwa/projects/moza-core-services/moza-user-services/target/classes/pl/moza/user/service/UserService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [pl.moza.user.service.UserService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.moza.dao.UserInterface] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at pl.moza.user.UserApplication.main(UserApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [pl.moza.user.service.UserService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.moza.dao.UserInterface] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.moza.dao.UserInterface] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1063) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at pl.moza.user.service.UserService.<init>(UserService.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Classes from data-service
Service, where I'm trying to get dao.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        userDao = (UserDao) ctx.getBean(UserDao.class);
    }
    //methods
```

Application:

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"pl.moza.user.*", "pl.moza.dao"})
public class UserApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And from datamodel-dao:

```
public class UserDao implements Serializable{
    @Inject
    UserInterface userInterface;
//methods
}
```

UserInterface is MyBatis interface, looking like this:

```
public interface UserInterface {

    public UserApp getUserByLogin(String login) throws Exception;
    //more methods
```

Problem is with wiring interface if I understand correctly. How can I fix this (and if it's possible - without changing datamodel-dao)?

Comment: Where is the concrete class implementation of your UserInterface?

Comment: It's in datamodel-dao/pl.moza/resources/pl.moza.dao/UserInterface.xml and it's mapped in datamodel-dao/pl.moza/resources/mybatis.configuration.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you are not using `@Component` or any equivalent xml configuration for `UserDao` then spring container (application context) will not create any bean and then spring container is not responsible for create or manage instance of it.
Another thing is i am not getting why you have used `@Inject` for `userInterface` ??? Instead you can implement it on `UserDao` and `@Autowired` it in `UserService`.

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDao implements UserInterface {
    //methods
}


@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDao")
    UserDao userDao;

    //methods
}
```

Make sure you have already added dependency of `datamodel-dao` in `user-services` and `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"pl.moza.user.*", "pl.moza.dao"})` covers actual required path.

Comment: Got to this, but thanks for answer :) actual problem is with UserInterface, which is MyBatis thing for communication with DB, and it's causing problem. I can load UserDAO, but can't UserInterface.

Comment: For your information As per Spring official documentation spring does not support Interface Injection.

Comment: @Elas, for your information As per Spring official documentation spring does not support Interface Injection. `1. Constructor Injection(E.g Pico Container, Spring supports it).
2. Setter Injection(E.g Spring supports it).
3. Interface Injection(E.g Avalon, Spring does not support it).` For more information  of my batis configuration please refer [here](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html) and [here](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/ko/sample.html).

Comment: Had to do some magic, but it worked after all:
Created interfaces in user-services, which were extending same interfaces from user-dao (without adding anything)
Coppied xml's with MyBatis SQLs to user-services

Then I had to use @Autowired for each interface (user-services version) used by DAO and use setFooInterface for each of them